# Use PreferenceFragment in Bottom Navigation Tabbed Application

Tags: android, fragment, preferencefragment

Main Activity:

```
switch (item.getItemId()) {
                        case R.id.action_item1:
                            selectedFragment = MeetingsFragment.newInstance();
                            break;
                        case R.id.action_item2:
                            selectedFragment = FriendsFragment.newInstance();
                            break;
                        case R.id.action_item3:
                            selectedFragment = PreferenceFragment.newInstance();
                            break;
                    }
                    //selectedFragment.setArguments(bundle);
                    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    transaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout, selectedFragment);
                    transaction.commit();
```

All the fragments extend android.support.v4.app.Fragment except PreferenceFragment(extends android.preference.PreferenceFragment).

Compiler is looking for android.support.v4.app.Fragment. I want to show preferences in one of the tab. Is their any solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

use [PreferenceFragmentCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/preference/PreferenceFragmentCompat.html) which is included in the support-v7 library

this class inherit from Fragment in v4 so it should work for you

Answer (score 1):

Let your `PreferenceFragment` extend [PreferenceFragmentCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/preference/PreferenceFragmentCompat.html).